# Are bank accounts linked to your address?

Tags: bank-account

Is it possible for a person or company to find my address with a bank account checking and routing number? Is it possible to verify that an address belongs to a certain bank account?

Comment: Can you add a country?

Comment: That would mean game on for fraudsters. Do you seriously think bank are so dumb that they would pass on this information to all and sundry and open themselves up for litigation ??

Answer (score 3):

Normally, [Dheer's answer is correct](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/24060/3546): there is no trivial way *in the general case* to get the account holder's address from only a bank account number and corresponding bank routing or clearing code.

However, **it might be possible in *specific* cases.** For example, the Swedish bank [Nordea allows you to choose to use the Swedish variant of a social security number (in Swedish called a person number) as the account number](https://www.nordea.se/privat/vardagstj%C3%A4nster/konton+och+betalningar/personkonto/200904.html). If one were to do that, then going from the account number to an address of residence for almost all such account holders simply involves calling the tax agency with that identity number in hand and asking for the corresponding name and address (which is public record).

Answer (score 2):

Based on just the account number and Routing number [or Bank Name / Identifiers] one cannot know the address of the account holder.
Only the Bank that has the account held knows the address of the account holder. They are not supposed to give this out [in most countries there are legal laws specifically protecting this information].

So apart from the law enforcement agency this information cannot be obtained by anyone from the Bank where the account is held.